# Visual Studio Code using kivy not able to print during the runtime

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

I am trying to using kivy recently. Created a simple app with .kv file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class BasePanel(Widget):
    textInputTitle = ObjectProperty(None)
    outputLabel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def OnButtonClicked(self):
        self.outputLabel.text = self.textInputTitle.text
        print("{}".format(self.textInputTitle.text))
        self.textInputTitle.text = ''

class StyledApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return BasePanel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    StyledApp().run()
```

The UI design file(I got no idea what should I call the *.kv file)

```
<BasePanel>
    textInputTitle: idTitle
    outputLabel: idOutput
    GridLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        cols: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text:"Title"
            TextInput:
                id: idTitle
                multiline: False
        Button:
            text:"Submit & Clear"
            on_press: root.OnButtonClicked()
        Label:
            id:idOutput
            text:"Echo"
```

The button handler works since the text can be transferred from the text input widget to the label at the bottom. But in the visual studio terminal, no message is printed. Only after the application is terminated then the messages were printed out in the terminal. Any suggestions to let the print function output messages to the vscode terminal in the runtime?

Environment

```
(base) mi@NZT1:~/workspace/py/kivy$ which python
/home/mi/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) mi@NZT1:~/workspace/py/kivy$ python --version
Python 2.7.16 :: Anaconda, Inc.
(base) mi@NZT1:~/workspace/py/kivy$ conda list | grep "kivy"
kivy                      1.11.1           py27h2394fcc_0    conda-forge
kivy-garden               0.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
(base) mi@NZL1:~/workspace/py/kivy$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Answer (score 0):

It was caused due to the Python extension using `conda run`. This has been reverted in the latest point release so it should work now.